# any stationary sequence can be embedded in a two-sided stationary sequence

Tags: probability-theory, ergodic-theory

In Durrett's probability theory and examples, it asks us to prove the following:

> Any stationary sequence $\{ X_n, n \ge 0\}$ can be embedded in a two-sided stationary sequence $\{ Y_n : n \in \mathbf{Z} \}$.

I know that $X_1, X_2, ... $ is a stationary sequence if $(X_1, X_2, ..., X_n)$ has the same distribution as $(X_k, X_{k+1}, ..., X_{k+n})$ for all $k > 0$. From google search, it seems like I need to use Kolmogorov's extension theorem to solve this, but what does it mean that a sequence can be "embedded" in another sequence? Additionally, what does "two sided sequence" mean?

> Theorem 2.1.21 (Kolmogorov's extension theorem) Suppose we are given probability measures $\mu_n$ on $(\mathbf{R}^n, \mathcal{R}^n)$ that are consistent, that is, $$\mu_{n+1}((a_1, b_1] \times \cdots \times (a_n, b_n] \times \mathbf{R}) = \mu_n ((a_1, b_1] \times \cdots \times (a_n, b_n]).$$ Then there is a unique probability measure $P$ on $(\mathbf{R}^N, \mathcal{R}^N)$ with $$P(\omega: \omega_i \in (a_i, b_i], 1 \le i \le n ) = \mu_n((a_1, b_1] \times \cdots \times (a_n, b_n])$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The precise statement of this result is as follows:

> For any stationary process $\{X_n\}_{n= 1}^{\infty}$, there exists a [doubly-infinite](https://oeis.org/wiki/Doubly_infinite_sequences) stationary sequence $\{Y_n\}_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}$ s.t. $X_1,\ldots$ and $Y_1,\ldots$ have the same distribution.

*Proof*. By Kolmogorov's extension theorem, it suffices to define the finite dimensional distributions of $\{Y_n\}$. Specifically, for $m,n\ge 0$ set
\begin{align*}
&\mathsf{P}(Y_{-m}\le y_{-m}, Y_{-m+1}\le y_{-m+1},\ldots, Y_{n-1}\le y_{n-1},Y_{n}\le y_n) \\
&\qquad=\mathsf{P}(X_{1}\le y_{-m}, X_2\le y_{-m+1},\ldots, X_{n+m}\le y_{n-1},X_{n+m+1}\le y_n).
\end{align*}

Comment: do you mean $X_{n+m+1}$ on the rhs?

Comment: Yes, you're right.

Comment: I think I understand the mapping from Y to X (similar to mapping $\mathbb{Z} \mapsto \mathbb{N}$). but do you mind explaning how Kolmogorov's extension theorem works intuitively? The theorem in the book is so vague and abstract, I'm not sure how defining a finite dimensional distribution allows us to extend to infinite distribution with the theorem.

Comment: The idea behind the extension theorem is a generalization of the following result to infinite-dimensional cases. Given a distribution function $F$, there exists a probability space $(\Omega,\mathcal{F},\mathsf{P})$ and a random variable $X$ living on that space s.t. $\mathsf{P}(X\le x)=F(x)$. The construction is very simple. We take $(\Omega,\mathcal{F})=(\mathbb{R},\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}))$ and $\mathsf{P}$ s.t. $\mathsf{P}((a, b])=F(b)-F(a)$. Then $X(\omega)=\omega$ has the required distribution.

Comment: In the infinite-dimensional case we start with finite dimensional distributions that satisfy certain consistency property and arrive to a similar conclusion, i.e., we construct a probability space and a stochastic process having the same finite-dimensional distributions.

Comment: A relatively simple proof of this result can be found in Section 9.2 of [this book](https://books.google.nl/books?id=WTGmDAAAQBAJ&printsec=frontcover&dq=shiryaev+probability&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjvv6ektP3vAhUs_7sIHRKBC9kQ6wEwAXoECAYQAQ#v=onepage&q=shiryaev%20probability&f=false).

Comment: i see. I'll definitely check out the link. Thank you!